# Hide keyboard ios by clicking the button using Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I developed an app using Ionic and I need to hide the ios keyboard by clicking the button. I installed the plugin ionic keyboard:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

I used this command and did not work:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
```

I am using this version of the Ionic with real device ios 8.

```
<link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/css/ionic.css" />

<script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.13/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to config.xml in addition to your command and it worked

```
<feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your app.js

Change this line

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
```

to

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

This will show the Accessory Bar of the keyboard with a "done" button on it.

You can close the keyboard more natively.

Hope it helps.